# Get specific item from array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a array in my code . My array contains mutliple boolean . I want to check that if a single false exists in my array then it returns false otherwise true . I did following

```
var results = self.resultCollection();

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length ; i++) {

        if (!results[i]) {
            self.isModelValid = false;
            break;
        } else {
            self.isModelValid = true;
        }
    }
```

Now i hear from somebody that there is some thing in jquery call `grap` or may be `grasp` , i am not confirmed . He told me that that `grap`/`grasp` will give you that thing in one line . Anyone knows about that .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: it is `grep` , look: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var results = self.resultCollection();
self.isModelValid = $.grep(results, function(n){return n}).length == results.length;
```

If the length of the filtered array returned by `$.grep` is the different from the original array, that means that at least one of the item is `false`. When they aren't the same, `self.isModelValid` will also be `false`, creating the effect you want.

---

### Explanation

```
$.grep(results, function(n){return n})
```

`$.grep` removes all `false` values and returns a new array using the filter `return n` (only returning true items).

```
$.grep(results, function(n){return n}).length == results.length
```

The new array's length is then compared to the original array's length. If they are different, that means that at least one item is `false` and removed. If their lengths are the same, this will returns `true`. `false` if they are different.

```
self.isModelValid = ...
```

The boolean is then assigned to `self.isModelValid`.

---

`$.grep` works, but it might not be the best practice in your case. jQuery will try to evaluate the whole array and returning a new one, increasing the performance cost. Use [Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17007211/283863)'s code if your array only contains booleans.

On the other hand, if your array contains multiple types and you are already using jQuery, this might be the best way to do it.

Comment: That's really-really bad, it doesn't short-circuit.

Comment: @kirelagin - What I was asking is what do you mean `it doesn't short-circuit`?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I mean that you _always_ evaluate the whole collection. Not to mention that you are creating a new one, as large as the collection in question.

Comment: @kirelagin - I thought he would want to know more about `grep` that's why I used it in my example.

Comment: I think it would work  , but TechBytes is right can you explain `grep` with example code , because even i am unable to understand it and it will also help future readers

Comment: @user2413182 - Added explanation.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 thats look better . Thanks for favor .

Answer (score 2):

Just use `indexOf`:

```
var results = self.resultCollection();
self.isModelValid = (results.indexOf(false) === -1);
```

Or if you really need that extra dose of jQuery:

```
self.isModelValid = ($.inArray(false, results) === -1);
```

This'll only work if the value is actually `false`, not falsey (`0`, an empty string, etc.).

Comment: What if the OP is looking for _falsy_ values, but not exactly `false`? In this sense your code is not a drop-in replacement.

Comment: @kirelagin: OP explicitly mentioned booleans, so I would assume that they're actually `true`/`false`.

Answer (score 0):

[`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) could help here but it is pure JavaScript, not jQuery.

```
self.isModelValid = results.every(function(x){return x;});
```

Comment: what if i have false in middle and true at last index . I think in this case it will return true

Comment: @user2413182 What made you think so?

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
var results = self.resultCollection();
self.isModelValid = (results.indexOf(false) === -1);
```